# Disable pinch zoom mapsforge

Tags: android, mapsforge

How can I disable pinch zoom in mapsforge? It seems like zoom is not working properly. I've found this topic https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/3_FQZ97B4-Q. They say it has no methods to do that. But it is dated 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```